# how to develop JAX-WS webservice client?

Tags: spring, jax-ws

I have one requirement to develop web service client in standalone java application which is using spring framework. My question is how can i develop one java class which can be used to call a web service. All I have is location of the WSDL and wsdl file? Also this application should run in diff envt. where url of the WSDL is diff. So basically I want to externalize the url property if possible.

I heard about the using JaxwsproxFactoryBean from spring framework but not finding any good working example.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go with Spring, JaxwsProxyFactoryBean is the way to go. At least I did.

I followed this example:

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-mvc-3-accessing-web-services.html

I have not tried the exact code provided by this article, but I followed step-by-step and I made it work. And it is hassle-free: wsimport tool is used in this example for generating the classes and JaxwsProxyFactoryBean is used to inject the proxy:

```
<bean id="subscriptionJaxProxyService" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean"
 p:serviceInterface="org.krams.tutorial.oxm.SubscriptionPort"
 p:wsdlDocumentUrl="http://localhost:8081/spring-ws-standalone/krams/ws/subscription.wsdl"
 p:namespaceUri="http://krams915.blogspot.com/ws/schema/oss"
 p:serviceName="SubscriptionPortService"
 p:portName="SubscriptionPortSoap11"/>
```

Finally, inject a marshaller/unmarshaller through spring (e.g. Jaxb2Marshaller) to deserialize the web service's responses.

Notes:

- make sure to check the article it mentions at the beginning:

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-ws-mvc-implementing-client.html

- the most annoying part was to get wsimport to work. Make sure to use version 1.12, from repository:

  ```
  <pluginRepository>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
      <id>Java dot Net</id>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <name>Repository for JAX-WS commons</name>
  </pluginRepository>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you don't necessarily have to use Spring in order to create a web service client.

wsimport tool can be used for this purpose.

open the command prompt, change dir to where wsimport.bat / ws.import.sh is located and execute the command below.

wsimport -keep -verbose ${your wsdl location}

Several source files will have been generated (most probably )in a folder named com. The name of the top folder depends on the name of the top package you have used in your wsdl.